# ViewPage - Change the icon on the text

Tags: java, android, android-studio, viewpage

I faced with a problem I can not solve. How can you replace icons in the text resource. Let's say instead of the first icons - current , the second icon - finished .

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements PagerSlidingTabStrip.CustomTabProvider {

    private Context mContext;
    private final int[] ICONS = {
            R.drawable.selector_icon_active,
            R.drawable.selector_icon_inactive
    };

    public ViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void tabUnselected(View view) {
        view.setSelected(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void tabSelected(View view) {
        view.setSelected(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View getCustomTabView(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        FrameLayout customLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, parent, false);
        ((ImageView) customLayout.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(ICONS[position]);
        return customLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

      //  return null;
       return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ICONS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
            default:
                bundle.putSerializable("TYPE", NotificationsType.ACTIVE);
                break;
            case 1:
                bundle.putSerializable("TYPE", NotificationsType.INACTIVE);
                break;
        }
        Fragment fragment = new TabFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```